# run browser from remote machine

Tags: browser, ssh, remote-desktop, lynx

I can connect to a remote machine using ssh,
I would like to open a URL from the remote machine. Well, I can do this using lynx (a command line browser), but then, javascript etc... gets messed up.

Is there a way I can open the URL and see it in my local machine firefox browser for example ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, if you do X over ssh (may require "ssh -X" option), then you can run graphical apps across ssh.  Assumes of course that the X client/server are all installed and working...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should look into using ssh as a proxy server. http://ocaoimh.ie/how-to-use-ssh-as-a-proxy-server/